# How to set max number of redeliveries with Java Camel DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

I want to use redelivering limit to 2 times. On redelivery the `RedeliveryProcessor.process()` should run.

```
public class SimpleRouteBuilder2 extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy = redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries(2);

        onException(CamelCustomException.class)
            .process((exchange) -> System.out.println("Handling exception..." + exchange))
            .onRedelivery(new RedeliveryProcessor())
            .redeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy)
            .log("Received body...")
            .handled(true);

        from("file:src/main/resources/data/input?noop=true")
            .process(new MyProcessor())
            .to("file:src/main/resources/data/output");
    }

}
```

```
public class RedeliveryProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("redelivery processor...");
    }

}
```

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello test");
        throw new CamelCustomException();
    }

}
```

but above code redelivers more than 2 times and `RedeliveryProcessor.process()` does not being run:

> hello test
>   hello test
>   hello test
>   hello test
>   hello test
>   hello test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the [error handler](https://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html) that is active (by default the DefaultErrorHandler).

You can configure it on Context level (for all routes) or on Route level. There are lots of options for redelivery.

```
errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
    .maximumRedeliveries(5)
    .redeliveryDelay(10000));
```